# How to login automatically to Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible let the client remember the password in some way? I am getting crazy inserting it again and again and again after the infamous error 37.

If there's not a way to do this using a client setting and you know an external program that could help me achieve the auto-login, that would also be helpful.

Comment: You can paste your password into the box, although having your password on your clipboard is less than ideal, security-wise.

Comment: easiest way is to write an autoit script but again, your password will be in plain text so not ideal

Comment: @StrixVaria - Copying and Pasting your password is as secure as typing it in.  Your password no matter how you place it in the password box will be plain text up until the point the client sends it to the authentication server.

Comment: @Ramhound All I meant was that it's easier for a user to accidentally their password into the wrong place (like a chat room) if it's sitting right there on the clipboard.

Comment: Actually you could just use something like KeePass, where you have the option to specify a timeout on the clipboard when you copy anything from it (the default is 12 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the same answer I gave when the [same question was asked about Starcraft 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6663/3241):

Once upon a time, there was a way to make World of Warcraft (Blizzard's other giant game) remember your password. You could edit certain files to have your password be filled in automatically.

Blizzard specifically disabled this ability, by removing all ability to change the login screens. They did this in part to prevent spyware/viruses from editing them (to steal your password), and in part because many people play Blizzard games on shared computers and in cyber-cafes, where saved passwords could lead to all sorts of mischief.

So, you can't directly save your password for a Blizzard game. At least not until 2027 when you can install ActivisFaceBlizzTwitterBook directly into your cerebral cortex.

[Carl's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6660/3241) mentions some ways to get around this; however, save your password into a macro hotkey program at your own risk.

**Update for D3:** Although your password must be entered each time, Blizzard has a new ["intelligent login"](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2226156035) feature related to entering your authenticator code. If this feature is enabled in your Battle.net account (enabled by default), then when you consistently log in from the same location, you should not have to enter your authenticator code on every login; you just have to enter it once a week and/or if your IP address changes. This means you can at least enter the password from muscle memory and not have to access your authenticator (after finding the darn thing on your desk of course).

Comment: Your comment about the authenticator is wrong.  That is a Battle.net security setting, by default that is the behavior, but you can set it to request the authenticator code each and every time if you want.

Comment: `If they detect that you are logging in from the same location as last time, you will not have to enter your authenticator code.` is pretty much false, I have to type it *every single time*.

Comment: I apologize if I did not describe the authenticator feature 100% precisely, as I was just summarizing it. I will edit with more info. @TomWijsman, you way wish to consult [this Q&A](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29413/sc2-keeps-asking-for-authenticator-code-new-intelligent-login-feature-not-wor) regarding your issue.

Comment: @Wikwocket - Its important to describe a security feature as precisely as possible.  Which is the reason I pointed it out.  I really wish good questions like this could be locked.  There isn't that much else that can said on this subject that is productive.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the massive number of account thefts, Blizzard forces you to enter your password every time you log-in to the game.  There is a client setting for remembering your battle.net email, and if you have an authenticator, Blizzard streamlined it a little by not requesting it if you always log in from the same IP.  However, as far as your password, the only way to speed it up would be to copy/paste it from a text file.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked down. This is fairly correct.

Comment: However, it is ridiculous that you have to enter the password again after an error 37 etc.

Comment: Well, when you think about it, an error 37 happens when the "servers are under heavy load."  So to fix it, it's gotta kick people off-line to recover, and it can't let you back on until it can handle it.  Now if you want to say that it's ridiculous that their servers are having issues in the first place, I'll agree with you there.

Comment: @JamesJiao - I marked it down because it easily could have been a comment to one of the author questions that talked about the authentication system Blizzard uses.

Answer (score 1):

No,

Blizzard does not allow saved passwords in any of their games, there could be many reasons for this that I could think of. For example, because they sell licenses and not software, to prevent unauthorized account access if someone is on your computer or simply for the added layer of scrutiny that it is you who is logging into your account. However that is not in the scope of the question.

You could use a keyboard emulator to type in your password, such as a program or keyboard with macro keys. However, it is best to not leave your password sitting in memory or a plain text file.

Instead, just get comfortable in typing your password in. Make is [sufficiently long](http://xkcd.com/936/) so you can practice your typing skills and get your "words per minute" speed up while your waiting to log in.

Comment: Leaving your password in memory is as secure as typing it.  There is not a secure way to protect your password if you are already infected with malware.  Programs that encrypt your keyboard buffer is hogwash, only programs that support said program, benefit from said feature.

Comment: As long as that's the only way a password can be compromised, sure. If it's also the case that you may accidentally paste it where you don't mean to (missed your next copy command, or forgot you overwrote your clipboard with your password) or that somebody with physical access to your machine could check your clipboard, then there is a significant loss of security by putting your password somewhere that is just a keystroke or menu option from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.autohotkey.com is what you want

Here is a forum post on their forums for a script that logs into Starcraft automatically - I'm sure you could adapt it to Diablo 3 without too much trouble.

http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=62524&p=383396&hilit=login+starcraft#p383396

Answer (score -4):

Run the game with the following command-line options: `-launch -autologin:yes -username:xx -password:xxx -launch -account:{0} -password:{1} -autologin:{2}`

{2} is either 1 or 0

Comment: Doesn't work. I, in all my naivety, have actually tried it.